# unable to update a mongodb collection from the graphql mutation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am having trouble solving the following issue. I satrted to develop GraphQL server using NodeJS, Apollo and Mongoose.

Below are some of the sample data from the database:

**PrescriptionSetup**

```
{
                "_id": "5ea99ae6fc48d036e083ec20",
                "name": "Calcium",
                "valueTo": -51,
                "valueFrom": -75,
                "treatmentDescription": "Deficiency",
                "recommendation": "<p><strong>Calcium Deficiency</strong></p>\n<p><strong>S &amp; S include: </strong></p>\n<p>Anxiety, Muscle cramps, and spasms, Bruising, Nervousness, Insomnia, Osteoporosis, Tooth decay</p>\n<p><strong>Calcium sources:</strong></p>\n<p>Milk, cheese and other dairy&Acirc;&nbsp;foods. Broccoli, cabbage and okra, Soya beans, Nuts, Flour,&nbsp;Fish</p>",
                "isNormal": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea99ae6fc48d036e083ec21",
                "name": "Calcium",
                "valueTo": 100,
                "valueFrom": 76,
                "treatmentDescription": "High Bio-unavailable",
                "recommendation": "<p><strong>Calcium Excess</strong></p>\n<p><strong>S &amp; S include:</strong></p>\n<p>Arthritis, Gall stones, Constipation, Kidney stones, Depression, Mental, Fatigue.</p>\n<p><strong>Calcium sources:</strong></p>\n<p>Milk, cheese and other dairy&nbsp;foods.Broccoli, cabbage and okra, Soya beans, Nuts, Flour, Fish</p>",
                "isNormal": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea99ae6fc48d036e083ec89",
                "name": "Calcium",
                "valueTo": -26,
                "valueFrom": -50,
                "treatmentDescription": "Border line deficiency",
                "recommendation": "<p><strong>Calcium Borderline Deficiency</strong></p>\n<p><strong>S &amp; S include: </strong></p>\n<p>Fatigue.Weak and brittle fingernails.Poor appetite. Muscle cramps, stiffness, and spasms.</p>\n<p><strong>Calcium sources:</strong></p>\n<p>Milk, cheese and other dairy&Acirc;&nbsp;foods. Broccoli, cabbage and okra, Soya beans.<br /> Nuts. Flour.&nbsp;Fish</p>",
                "isNormal": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea99ae6fc48d036e083ec8a",
                "name": "Calcium",
                "valueTo": -76,
                "valueFrom": -100,
                "treatmentDescription": "insufficiency",
                "recommendation": "<p><strong>Calcium Insufficiency</strong> <br /><strong>S &amp; S include: </strong></p>\n<p>Anxiety, Muscle cramps and spasms, Bruising, Nervousness, Insomnia, Osteoporosis, Tooth decay</p>\n<p><strong>Calcium sources:</strong></p>\n<p>Milk, cheese and other dairy&Acirc;&nbsp;foods.Broccoli, cabbage and okra, Soya beans , Nuts , Flour , Fish</p>",
                "isNormal": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea99ae6fc48d036e083ec22",
                "name": "Magnesium",
                "valueTo": 100,
                "valueFrom": 76,
                "treatmentDescription": "High Bio-unavailable",
                "recommendation": "<p><strong>Magnesium Excess</strong></p>\n<p><strong>S &amp; S include:</strong></p>\n<p>Confusion, Fatigue, Depression, Low blood pressure, Diarrhea, Muscle weakness</p>\n<p><strong>Magnesium sources:</strong></p>\n<p>Spinach, figs, avocado, banana and raspberries. Nuts and seeds. Legumes. Peas, broccoli, cabbage, green beans, artichokes, Seafood</p>",
                "isNormal": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea99ae6fc48d036e083ec53",
                "name": "Magnesium",
                "valueTo": 25,
                "valueFrom": -25,
                "treatmentDescription": "Normal / Ideal zone",
                "recommendation": "",
                "isNormal": true
            },
```

**ParsedPdf**

```
 {
_id: "5eb2da3a4c6ccc6f65d7e621",
"mineralTestReport": 
[
    {
        "name": "Calcium",
        "value": "25",
        "details": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Magnesium",
        "value": "-25",
        "details": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Phosphorus",
        "value": "-71",
        "details": null
    },
    ],
    "ratios": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Ca/Mg",
            "value": "43",
            "details": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Ca/P",
            "value": "100",
            "details": null
        },
        {
            "name": "K/Na",
            "value": "-75",
            "details": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Cu/Zn",
            "value": "-3",
            "details": null
        }
    ]}
```

What I wanted to do is, take the "**name**" and "**value**" from each of the array on the **ParsedPdf**, check where the "**value**" lies in between the "**valueFrom**" and "**valueTo**" from the **PrescriptionSetup** and update the "**detail**" with "**description**" and "**recommendation**".

This is what I did. I created a Mutation:

```
updateParsePdf: authenticated(async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      try {
        const pdf = await ParsePdf.findById(args._id);
        const newReport = await updatedReport(pdf._doc);
        const reportUpdated = await ParsePdf.findByIdAndUpdate(args._id, {
          newReport,
        }).exec();
          return reportUpdated._doc;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
        throw new AuthenticationError("Opps! Something went wrong.", error);
      }
    }),
```

**updateReport method**

```
    const updatedReport = async (pdf) => {
    //pdf is the response from the ParsedPdf above
  let updated = {};
  try {
    await Object.keys(pdf).forEach((key) => {
      const field = pdf[key];
      if (Array.isArray(field)) {
        const newRep = field.map(async (f) => {
          const pp = PrescriptionSetup.find({
            name: f.name,
            valueFrom: {
              $lte: f.value,
            },
            valueTo: {
              $gte: f.value,
            },
          })
            .exec()
            .then((p) => {
              return {
                ...f,
                details: {
                  description: p[0].treatmentDescription,
                  recommendation: p[0].recommendation,
                  isNormal: p[0].isNormal,
                },
              };
            })
            .catch((e) => {
              console.log("Error finding setup: ", e);
            });
          return pp;
        });
        updated = { ...updated, [key]: [...newRep] };
      }
    });
    const aa = { ...pdf, ...updated };
    return aa;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error...: ", error);
  }
};
```

There are lots of Arrays inside the ParsedPdf collection with lots of items in it. I think because of the huge db queries, I could not make it work. 
What is the best approach to solve this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Ar you sure `value`  in `ParsedPdf ` is a `String`? While `valueFrom `, `valueTo` are `Number`s? And what's not working are there errors or it just doesn't update as it supposed to?

Comment: Your issues I have observed are mostly concerning async operations. You forgot to put `await` on some places where it should appear and you put them where it shouldn't appear

Comment: @TheeSritabtim Can you show me the correct place for the `await` ? The `find` query is working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest an approach with the least code change.

1. `const pp = PrescriptionSetup.find` here `pp` is a `Promise`, so `newRep` will be array of `Promise`s

   *instead of `[...newRep]` use `[...await Promise.all(newRep)]`*
2. `await Object.keys(pdf).forEach((key) => ...)` here `.forEach` doesn't return anything, actually you don't have to `await`, but we just aded an async logic in (1.) so we have to handle that

   *change to `await Promise.map(Object.keys(pdf), async (key) => ...)` if you use `bluebird`, else use something equivalent with Promise.map*

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. Hadn't heard of `bluebird` before, gave it a try. Thanks for the suggestion .